# How to get the color of a Drawable in Android

Tags: android, drawable

in one part of my code I have the following code:

```
linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

In the other part I want to get the background color that was set, something like:

```
linearLayout.getBackgroundColor();
```

But there is no method like this, there is only this method:

```
Drawable drawable = linearLayout.getBackground();
```

How can I get the color of a drawable? (I don't want to extend the LinearLayout and manually storing the background color etc.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
((ColorDrawable)linearLayout.getBackground()).getColor();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
Drawable bg = view.getBackground();
if (bg instanceof ColorDrawable){
   color = ((ColorDrawable) bg).getColor();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ColorDrawable in something similar to this:

```
Drawable background = linearLayout.getBackground();
if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
        Color color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
((ColorDrawable) linearLayout.getBackground()).getColor();
```

BTW, I figured this out by looking at the source code for [`View.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java):

```
public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
    if (mBackground instanceof ColorDrawable) {
        ((ColorDrawable) mBackground.mutate()).setColor(color);
        computeOpaqueFlags();
        mBackgroundResource = 0;
    } else {
        setBackground(new ColorDrawable(color));
    }
}
```